# Cloudinary on Flutter Web + Mobile Application

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, flutter-web, cloudinary

I actually started a project for media streaming and using cloudinary for video storage and flutter as front end.Now i'm actually going through an issue on the video player side.Cloudinary already got a video player sdk but they are not providing support for Flutter yet.What i wish to accomplish is,

Play HLS [ HTTP Live Streaming ] using an embedded video player in Flutter  with

- Option to play subtitles [ This is automatically generated by cloudinary ]
- Options to play video on different formats [ 4k , HD , Normal etc <- files will be provided by cloudinary ]
- Fast forward option , Fast rewind option
- This all must work on Web and Mobile side [ android + ios ]

The choices in front of me was

**Going for Existing Video Player Plugin**

I tried to test this with some existing plugins but they have compatibility issues working on both mobile and web and most of them doesn't provide all these functionalities

**Create something from scratch**

There was a subtitle wrapper plugin for the flutter normal video player plugin.I can also create an overlay for placing the fast forward and fast rewind buttons,also for switching the resolutions. But i found out that flutter video player doesn't play HLS [ HTTP Live Streaming ] Media ( .m3u8 )Files .

Right now iam really stuck at this position. I'm looking for a stable solution to go ahead. Please guide me with your XP ..

**Thanks in Advance**